# what is meant by 'programmable variations of a font'

Tags: java, fonts

I am checking problem related to rendering and fonts. Comments in  [GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts()](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts%28%29)  mentions ' programmable variations' of a font.

> This method provides for the application the most precise control over
>   which Font instance is used to render text. If a font in this
>   GraphicsEnvironment has **multiple programmable variations**, only one
>   instance of that Font is returned in the array, and other variations
>   must be derived by the application.
>
> **If a font** in this environment **has multiple programmable variations**,
>   such as Multiple-Master fonts, only one instance of that font is
>   returned in the Font array. The other variations must be derived by
>   the application.

What is meant by 'programmable variations' here?  How can I know if a Font has 'programmable variations' in this GraphicsEnvironment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it gives the example of multiple master fonts:
see this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_master_fonts) on MM Fonts.

This is an implementation by Adobe achieving multiple programmeable fonts, where you can "create a wide gamut of typeface styles of different widths, weights and proportions, without losing the integrity or readability of the character glyphs"